# Best books/resources for learning QTP as a beginner

Tags: testing, qtp, regression-testing

I am working in a company working primarily in manual testing. Now for a specific project they require me to learn QTP. I will be given training but I don't think it will suffice. I am seeking some books/web links for tutorials and videos. I am novice in QTP, so would prefer books on a beginner's level.

Comment: the following blog is good from Yogi Shukla
http://dimyo.blogspot.co.uk

Answer (score 4):

The best learning materials that we found for QTP is its "Help".

So first install QTP on your system. Click on the 'Help' button in toolbar. You will get lots of documents, user guide. You can save these in PDF format also.There are few videos on latest modification in QTP.

If you don't know any keyword, method, statement then write that keyword in QTP Expert View pane or simply select it. Select the keyword and hit 'F1' key from keyword. Help will open in new window for that keyword.

Besides this basic and most powerful source you can visit various forums, blogs, YouTube videos etc. Please find some of them at
http://forum.softwaretestinghelp.com/index.php/topic,4301.msg4112.html#msg4112

There are many more.

Better you start with Guru99 videos.

Answer (score 3):

These are some links that have helped me alright:

http://www.joecolantonio.com/ (in there there are many useful books linked to Amazon too)

http://www.nucleation.in/

http://www.funandknowledge.blogspot.in/

http://qtpprashanth.blogspot.com.es/

http://blogs.e-gineering.com/Christian/

http://motevich.blogspot.com.es/search/label/QTP

http://quicktestprofessional.wordpress.com/

I hope that helps